# Man goes to a science conference, gets turned invisible along with a cat

Tags: story-identification

Please identify the novel in which a man goes to a science conference with a woman he wants to sleep with and gets turned invisible (along with a cat) when activists sabotage the project inside the buildings lab. There was an "explosion" and a crater, but the crater was a globe that contained the intact but invisible building, the man, and a cat.

I think I read it in the 1990's. It was written in the first person.

Comment: Incidentally, the cat is homage to the original ''The Invisible Man'' book where Griffin first tested his procedure on a cat, who managed to escape. He claimed to have heard its yowling for days, but never could find it.

Comment: @seadduggan - I suspect this was supposed to be a comment on my answer, not the original question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Memoirs of an Invisible Man](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/reviews/books/0-440-20122-5.html)" by H.F. Saint.

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoirs_of_an_Invisible_Man);

> While there, Nick sees a group of Marxist student protesters who
>   demonstrate nuclear catastrophe by **attempting to explode a cat**. To get
>   everyone away from the MicroMagnetics presentation, they cut off power
>   to the laboratory where nuclear equipment is operating. The control
>   computers lose function and in a flash of eerie light, **everything in a
>   fifty-foot radius becomes invisible, including Nick.**

The concept of an invisible globe/crater was also shown in the film of the [same name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104850/).

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Now I have a movie to enjoy. Thank you.

Comment: @MajorStackings Don't be so sure- the lead role is played by Chevy Chase.